# Using \t regex with Scanner input

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

```
String[] splitUp = line.split("\t");
```

This is the code and the string is this `"John Doe    3.30    23123123"`
The problem is at the end of Doe and after 3.30 those spaces are actually tabs. Now I have to split up this string by the tabs and \t and \t aren't working. Help

Here is more code:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){


          String line = scan.nextLine();
          String[] splitUp = line.split("\\t");
          for(int i = 0; i < splitUp.length; i++){
              System.out.println(splitUp[i]);
          }
```

}

and I have a text file which is feeding in lines with tabs.

Answer:

if editing a .txt file with the java compiler IntelliJ then it replaces the \t char with the corresponding amount of spaces, therefore you cannot check for \t because it doesn't exist. you have to edit it in a regular text editor and all will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java you need `\\t` to also escape the `\`.

following code works:

```
String test="asd    asd asd xsdv";
String[]t=test.split("\\t");
for(String st : t){
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

output is:

```
asd
asd
asd xsdv
```

Comment: String[] splitUp = line.split("\\t"); so this?

Comment: yes that should it be

Comment: nope, still doesn't split

Comment: i updated my answer with some test code that works

Comment: my output doesn't split

Comment: asd    asd asd is what i get

Comment: paste more code than just that line, because my code works just fine

Comment: i added more code if that helps

Comment: and you are sure that those are tabs coming in and not 4 single spaces?

Comment: well when i do 4 spaces it works. however i am typing a tab

Comment: it works sorry!

Comment: you are welcome. what was the problem?

Comment: The problem was that when editing a .txt file in intellij it replaces the white space \t with a corresponding amount of actual spaces. I had to edit it in a regular text file and then it worked.

Comment: ahh well good to know

Answer (score 0):

You can use it and then save each group => Array

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\w+\\s\\w+|\\d+.\\d+)";
final String string = "John Doe 3.30    23123123";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Input:

```
John Doe    3.30    23123123
```

Output:

```
John Doe
3.30
23123123
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/Us6G3X/1

Comment: your regex only works with your example. what happens if the string changes?